# Can i Use the attribute "Value" as a selector in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having list of input text boxes in a HTML form, When i click on the form all the text boxes should be validated. i Want to focus the first text which one is empty. can i use

```
$("input[value=""]:first").focus()
```

But it shows error .i am validate my using normal jquery validation as follow 
like

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".textbox").blur(function(){ 
      if($(this).val()=="")
     {
         $(this).addClass("error")
      }
   }) ;
  });
</script>
```

Any suggestion much appreciated.  I dont to use any plugin for validation

Comment: `$('input[value=""]:first').focus()` - your string format is nor correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong combination of double quotes. You have to use combination of single and double quote. The first pair of double make the string `"input[value="` and second `"]:first"` and `"input[value=""]:first"` is not a valid string to make a selector.

```
$('input[value=""]:first').focus();
```

You can check that the selector you had has syntax error [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/sDbgN/), because your wrong combination of double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your approach is not going to work. Putting values into your inputs won't register a change to the DOM `value` attribute which is what your selector is looking for.

Here's a demonstration ~ http://jsfiddle.net/uLm2J/

What you want to do find the first input with an empty `value` *property*, for example...

```
$('input').filter(function() {
    return !this.value;
}).eq(0).focus();
```

Demo here ~ http://jsfiddle.net/uLm2J/1/

Answer (score 0):

on blur of input field you need to set value attribute with its value

http://jsfiddle.net/uLm2J/2/

here is the code

```
$('#go').on('click', function() {
    if(typeof $('input[value=""]:first')[0] !="undefined")
    $('input[value=""]:first')[0].style.border='2px solid red';    
});
$("input").blur(function(e){
    e.target.setAttribute("value",e.target.value);
});
```